# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Node.js logs has no timestamp

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am very new to using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and deploying Node.js applications on it. I was trying to debug an issue with my Node app and I noticed the Node.js logs do not have time stamps. How can I add time stamps to the Node js logs.

This is what the current log looks like:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log
-------------------------------------
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:31
            throw err;
            ^

InvalidParameterValue: Missing required header 'To'.
    at Request.extractError (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:47:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:673:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:675:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/app/current/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)
```

Comment: Whenever you are logging the error (if you are using express it is usually at the bottom of the app.js file) you can add a line before or after logging the error like `console.log(new Date())`

Comment: @JoeLissner Is there a better way to handle logging? I am currently just using `throw`. I am fairly new to Node.js development. How should I log the errors without having to add `console.log(new Date())` everytime I `throw` an error

Answer (score 0):

Okay after research I found out that I can control this.  Because I was just doing `throw error` it was not displaying the timestamp.  I've been recommended to use some several different logging packages, but this is the one I will most likely be going with:

https://github.com/starak/node-console-stamp/

If anyone has any better suggestions please let me know.